# SQL-Finding differences between 2 queries

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

I have 2 queries with different logic and I'm trying to find the difference between the two.

For example:

- Query 1: Selecting all the names with vowels, total:10
- Query 2: Selecting all the names ending in vowels, total:2

How would I go about finding the 8 remaining values between the 2 queries? I have tried doing the following but still no luck:

```
Q1 except Q2 
UNION
Q2 except Q1
```

Answer (score 6):

```
(Query for Selecting all the names with vowels)

EXCEPT

(Query for Selecting all the names ending in vowels)
```

Comment: just Q1 except Q2, and make sure Q1 returns more than Q2 does

Answer (score 2):

Another option is writing the query with the desired `where` clauses.

```
select *
from t
where name like '%[aeiou]%' 
  and name not like '%[aeiou]'
```

Another option using two [common table expressions](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175972.aspx) and `not exists()`:

```
with q1 as (
/* query 1 */
)
, q2 as (
/* query 2 */
)
select *
from q1
where not exists (
  select 1 
  from q2
  where q1.name = q2.name
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Following your description, the result of query 1 must contain the reuslt of query2.
So you can use

```
Q1 EXCEPT Q2
```

Or Q1 where NOT EXISTS Q2

Answer (score 0):

EXCEPT will be costly if you are querying against a large data. So you can go with LEFT OUTER JOIN

```
select * from Q1 left outer join Q2 on Q1.ID=Q2.ID where Q2.ID IS NULL
```